# Confusion in total probability theorem

Tags: probability

> On a normal standard die one of the $21$ dots from any of the six faces
>   is removed at random with each dot equally likely to be chosen. If the
>   die is then rolled, then find the probability that the odd number
>   appears.

I defined E as : Odd appears from altered die.

Let DRi denote the probability of dot being removed from $i^{th}$ face

Now $P(E) = \sum _{i=1}^6P(DRi)P(O/DRi)$ // Total probability theorem.

I have got the right answer $= 11/21$ after calculating this.

But my question is that I am not sure how the event E intersects with all the events DRi. The two have completely different sample spaces. So how can they intersect? I think there's an issue here relating to my understanding of sample spaces.  I am unable to visualize E and DRi together.

Answer (score 1):

The event $E$ is the event that "an odd number appears from the **altered die**". That last part is important. It means that the event $E$ cannot simply be described as

$$\{1,3,5\}$$

because the possibility that $1$ appears from the $2$-face with one dot removed is a different one from the one where $1$ appears from the $1$-face when a dot was removed from the $5$-face.

Therefore, the probability space $\Omega$ must be changed. One way to describe the new space is with elements being tuples of the form

$$(f, e)$$

where $f\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the face that is rolled, and $e$ is the face from which a dot was erased. In this case, you have, for example,

$$(1,3)\in E$$

because, if $1$ is rolled and the $3$ face had a dot erased, then indeed, an odd number appeared, but you also have

$$(2,2)\in E$$

because the $2$-face appeared, but one dot was erased from the $2$-face, so an odd number appeared.

Similarly, you have

$$(1,2)\in E, (1,3)\in E, (1,4)\in E, (1,5)\in E, (1,6)\in E, (4,4)\in E, (6,6)\in E$$ and so on, while $(1,1)\notin E$.

More thoroughly, $$E=\{(e,f)|e\text{ is odd and }f\neq e\}\cup\{(e,e)|e\text{ is even}\}$$

The event $DR_i$ is simply the set $$\{(e, i)| e\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$$

and now, clearly, it makes sense to talk about the intersection of $E$ with $DR_i$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you show this through a venn diagram like thing? The answer as it stands is too abstract for me to be able to make sense of.

Comment: @Abcd There are a total of $36$ elements in $\Omega$, that's not too many is it? You can draw them quite easily...

Comment: What do e mean in set DRi?

Comment: @Abcd $e$ is any number from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: Agreed that E will have duplets but how can DRi have duplets?

Comment: @Abcd Yes, $DR_i = \{(e, i)| e\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$. This means, for example, that $DR_1 = \{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6)\}$